# How to Update a Program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a program created in VB.Net called Technical Logs System. I publish it in a folder also called Technical Logs System and that folder contains the ff.

1. Application Files (File Folder)
2. setup (Application)
3. Technical Logs System (ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest)

The contents of this folder are what I use to install the system to other PCs.

How can I update the old system? For example, Technical Logs System is composed of one Form and on my next update I will add a new Form so it's 2 Forms now. How can I make it so the new form will add to the old one? What I mean is before starting the program the system will check for updates and install it. They say this is called patch or update but I don't know what term should be used. My goal here is to update the old system without requiring the user to uninstall and install the updated version on their own.

By the way, is it possible to make the source of updates 192.168.2.2, so when the user opens the system, the program will check update in 192.168.2.2 and install the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ClickOnce then you configure how application updates will be performed on the Publish page of the project properties.  If you don't configure updates to be performed automatically then you simply have to get the new published output to the user, e.g. by email attachment or download, and they run it like they would have the original installer.  The new version will simply replace the old version.  You don't have to do anything more.

Comment: Sir I`m using the Setup when Installing the Program so you mean sir that I will use the ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest when updating the System and that`s It? Can I do it Sir that If I will open the Program the System will check update in 192.168.2.2 and automatically Update it. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the Publish page of the project properties?  Have you read the documentation explaining what those options mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the project file properties of your app.
Switch to the Publish Tab.

In the `Publish Location` you insert a ftp server or file path where you want to store the published files of your application.

You can optionally also define a `Installation Folder` if it differs from the update folder.

You can also configure the publish, e.g. which files are being uploaded, which .NET Framework is used as a `Prerequisite` etc.

After you published your app via `Publish Now` all clients will get the update when they start their application the next time.

[image: Publich ClickOnce]

So in your example publish the Technical Logs System app once.

Add another Form to your system etc.

Republish -> Clients will get new version after restarting the app.